# Can't compile a new version of a translation

Tags: localization, ckan

I am trying to compile an updated .po file, following the instructions here http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/contributing/i18n.html#compile-a-translation , but the compilation fails.

I have updated a translation at Transifex, and extracted a .po file. 
I have copied the new .po file to

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/CKAN/i18n/no/LC_MESSAGES
```

(I deleted the old .po file first.)

I the ran the command to compile the new .po file:

```
python setup.py compile_catalog --locale no
```

I get the following error message:

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

There's no setup.py in that folder, but there is one several folders up (under /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/), so I also tried the following (still from the folder where the ckan.po file is):

```
python ../../../../setup.py compile_catalog --locale no
```

This time, I got the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'message_extractors'
warnings.warn(msg)
error in ckan setup command: Distribution contains no modules or packages for namespace package 'ckanext'
```

Is there something wrong in the documentation on how to compile translations, or is there something I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current directory is wrong. You should assume that all ckan commands are to be run from the root directory of ckan:

```
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
```

This is the sort of output you will get:

```
$ python setup.py compile_catalog --locale no
running compile_catalog
831 of 945 messages (87%) translated in 'ckan/i18n/no/LC_MESSAGES/ckan.po'
compiling catalog 'ckan/i18n/no/LC_MESSAGES/ckan.po' to 'ckan/i18n/no/LC_MESSAGES/ckan.mo'
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. (I also needed to activate paster first, http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.4.0/maintaining/paster.html -- I had forgotten that.)

Comment: I've added these steps to the docs now http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/contributing/i18n.html#manual-setup